# Get one value from from two different fields (radio, number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

I'm looking to collect input from a form as found on this image:

[image: freelancer question, radio button and text box]

Just like UpWork, I want to get one value from two different fields.

I tried this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="PostForm_freelancersToHire" class="required">How many freelancers do you need for this job?</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" data-ng-click="setManyFreelancers(false)" name="hMoreF"  ng-model="oneFreelancer" checked="checked" />
                    <span class=""></span>
                    I want to hire one freelancer
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" data-ng-click="setManyFreelancers(true)" name="hMoreF"  />
                    <span class=""></span>
                    I need to hire more than one freelancer
                </label>
            </div><!---->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" ng-if="hasManyFreelancers">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="number" name="oneMoreFreelancer" ng-model="oneMoreFreelancer" min="2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:5px 0 0">
            <span>Freelancers</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular JS:

```
$scope.setManyFreelancers = function (t) {
    if (t) {
        $scope.hasManyFreelancers = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.hasManyFreelancers = false;
        // $scope.oneMoreFreelancer = '';
    }
}
```

Both `$scope.oneMoreFreelancer` and `$scope.oneFreelancer` are `undefined`.

If the first radio is selected, I'd like its value. If the second radio is selected, I'd like the numerical input value. How do I properly fetch this?